# How to prewrite header before list all data in text file with c#

Tags: c#

I have example data like this

```
FamilyID;name;gender;DOB;Place of birth;status
1;nicky;male;01-01-1998;greenland;married
1;sonia;female;02-02-1995;greenland;married
2;dicky;male;04-01-1995;bali;single
3;redding;male;01-05-1996;USA;single
3;sisca;female;05-03-1994;australia;married
```

i must separate all data  by familyID

i already success to separate the data by family ID
so the result is

File 1:

```
1;nicky;male;01-01-1998;greenland;married
1;sonia;female;02-02-1995;greenland;married
```

File 2:

```
2;dicky;male;04-01-1995;bali;single
```

File 3:

```
3;redding;male;01-05-1996;USA;single
3;sisca;female;05-03-1994;australia;married
```

The problem is , the header is missing, for each file , i expect it to be like

Example for file 1 :

```
FamilyID;name;gender;DOB;Place of birth;status
1;nicky;male;01-01-1998;greenland;married
1;sonia;female;02-02-1995;greenland;married
```

etc.

This is the code i write

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string tgl = date.Date.ToString("dd");
            string bln = date.Month.ToString("d2");
            string thn = date.Year.ToString();
            string tglskrg = thn + "/" + bln + "/" + tgl;

            string filename = ("C:\\Users\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exampledata.txt");
            string[] liness = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            string[] col;

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

            // group by first value
            var groups = lines.Skip(1)
                  .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
                  .GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();

            // iterate groups write the joined lines back to a new file with the key name
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group);
                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exampledata_"+group.Key+".txt", group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)));
            }

            ...//line of code to zip file(already done too)
```

Maybe there is something i wrong or miss ?

thanks for the help

And i make it in visual express c# 2010, console application

Comment: so, what's the problem? `File.WriteAllLines()` writes all lines to a file. Just add your header to that lines.

Comment: if i put that header , it will be overwrite or not? because i already have the File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exampledata_"+group.Key+".txt", group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)) that will write the list of data based on familyID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take specific column and put header from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318772/how-to-take-specific-column-and-put-header-from-text-file)

Comment: add it to **lines** (to `group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)` specificly)

Comment: use something like `new[] { "FamilyID;name;gender;DOB;Place of birth;status" }.Concat(group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x))`

Comment: @vasily.sib wah, it works ,sry i didnt know how it works . Thankyou so much, it works now

Comment: You are welcome:) Also, your "the date to string" magic can be simplified to just one line: `var tglskrg = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy\\/MM\\/dd}"`

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks for the information and the knowledge, hope i can improve my coding skill . Thankyou once again